# Uncaught Error: [jqLite:nosel] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/jqLite/nosel & Warning: Tried to load angular more than once

Tags: angularjs, gulp, bower, fuse, quill

I wanted to add ng-quill rich text editor for my project. For that, I have installed quill and ng-quill using bower. (Referred :[ngQuill Documentation](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngQuill) && [quill is not a constructor 
 issue](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ng-quill/issues/85))

bower.json:

```
"quill": 
"https://github.com/quilljs/quill/releases/download/v1.1.5/quill.tar.gz",
"ngQuill": "ngquill#^3.8.0"
```

Then added the scripts for angular, quill and ngQuill in index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/quill/quill.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/ngQuill/src/ng- 
quill.js"></script>
```

Then, I have added ngQuill dependency in app module.
 (function ()
{
    'use strict';

```
/**
 * Main module
 */
angular
    .module('fuse', [

        // Core
        'app.core',

        'satellizer',
        'ngStorage',
        'ngFileSaver',
        'ui.tree',
        'as.sortable',
        'flow',
        'cfp.hotkeys',
        'infinite-scroll',
        'nvd3',
        'ngIdle',
        angularDragula(angular),
        'ngQuill'
    ]);
```

})();

Then, I have added the directive in html:

```
 <ng-quill-editor ng-model="vm.message" toolbar="true" link-tooltip="true" 
 image-tooltip="true" toolbar-entries="font size bold list bullet italic 
 underline strike align color background link image" editor-required="true" 
 required="" error-class="input-error"></ng-quill-editor>
```

Finally, after running locally, got error in console:

[image: error in console]

How to resolve this issue? The versions which I am using are(also i am using fuse theme):
angular: 1.5.11
bower: 1.8.4
gulp: 3.9.0
quill: 1.1.5
ng-quill: 3.8.0

Comment: As the error says you are loading angular somewhere twice

Comment: As i am adding the angular script in index.html the error occurs, and it is mandatory to add angular script for having rich text editor ngQuill. What can be the other way around?

Comment: Finally, it got resolved by adding the quill scripts inside the body and not adding those in the head. As gulp was loading all the bower dependency.